# I am getting these errors and do not understand how to fix

Tags: sql, oracle

- Error(25,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXEC"
- Error(30,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type      current cursor delete    exists prior The symbol "begin" was substituted for "SELECT" to continue.
- Error(30,22): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with          << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge

DROP TABLE Student;
COMMIT;

```
 CREATE TABLE Student(
    studentNumber INT NOT NULL,
    studentName VARCHAR2(20) NOT NUll,
    gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    highSchoolAvg INT NOT NULL,
    scholarship INT DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT "student_gender" CHECK (gender IN ('M', 'F')),
    CONSTRAINT "student_highSchoolAvg" CHECK (highSchoolAvg BETWEEN 0 AND       100)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AcceptStudent(
    studentNumberPR INT,
    studentNamePR VARCHAR2,
    genderPR CHAR,  
    highSchoolAvgPR INT)
IS
    ScholarshipPr INT;
BEGIN
    ScholarshipPR := 0;

    IF highSchoolAvgPR >= 90 and highSchoolAvgPR <=100 THEN
        ScholarshipPR := 1500;

    ELSIF highSchoolAvgPR >= 85 and highSchoolAvgPR < 90 THEN
        ScholarshipPR := 1000;

    ELSE
       raise_application_error(-20201, 'Invalid highSchool average');
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO Student (studentNumber, studentName, gender,     highSchoolAvg, scholarship) 
        VALUES (studentNumberPR, studentNamePR, genderPR,     highSchoolAvgPR, ScholarshipPr);
END;

exec ACCEPTSTUDENT (1, 'Ashley', 'F', 87);
exec ACCEPTSTUDENT (2, 'Will', 'M', 76);
exec ACCEPTSTUDENT (3, 'David', 'M', 94);
--Holly should be the only error--
exec ACCEPTSTUDENT (4, 'Holly', 'F', 103);
select * from student;
```

Comment: WOW. Your error message suggests this is Oracle but you tagged your question with both mysql and sql-server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle Stored Procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679733/oracle-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to execute everything from a script? You are missing a slash `/` by itself, on a separate line, after the procedure.